# Conditional subset of data from list base on date R

Tags: r, date, subset

I have several .csv files containing hourly data. Each file represents data from a point in space. The start and end date is different in each file.

The data can be read into R using:

```
lstf1<- list.files(pattern=".csv")

lst2<- lapply(lstf1,function(x) read.csv(x,header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep = ",",fill=TRUE, dec = ".",quote = "\""))

head(lst2[[800]])
             datetime precip code
1 2003-12-30 00:00:00     NA    M
2 2003-12-30 01:00:00     NA    M
3 2003-12-30 02:00:00     NA    M
4 2003-12-30 03:00:00     NA    M
5 2003-12-30 04:00:00     NA    M
6 2003-12-30 05:00:00     NA    M
```

`datetime` is `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS`, `precip` is the data value, `code`can be ignored.

For each dataframe (df) in `lst2` I want to select data for the period `2015-04-01` to `2015-11-30` based on the following conditions:

1) If `precip` in a `df` contains all `NAs`within this period, delete it (do not select)
2) If `precip` is not all `NAs` select it.

The desired output (`lst3`) contains the sub-setted data for the period `2015-04-01` to `2015-11-30`.

All dataframes in `lst3` should have equal length with `days` and `hours`without `precip`denoted as `NA`

The I can write the files in `lst3` to my directory using something like:

```
sapply(names(lst2),function (x)  write.csv(lst3[[x]],file = paste0(names(lst2[x]), ".csv"),row.names = FALSE))
```

[The link to a sample file can be found here (~200 KB)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lya8tiwxkax4c0/L112FN0M.262.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do, but this example (using dplyr, which has nice filter syntax) on the file you provided should get you close:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.csv ("L112FN0M.262.csv")
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

# Get the required date range and delete the NAs
df.sub <- filter(df, !is.na(precip), 
                     datetime >= as.POSIXct("2015-04-01"),
                     datetime < as.POSIXct("2015-12-01"))

# Check if the subset has any rows left (it will be empty if it was full of NA for precip)
if nrow(df.sub > 0) {
    df.result <- filter(df, datetime >= as.POSIXct("2015-04-01"), 
                            datetime < as.POSIXct("2015-12-01"))
    # Then add df.result to your list of data frames...
} # else, don't add it to your list
```

I think you are saying that you want to retain NAs in the data frame if there are also valid precip values--you only want to discard if there are NAs for the entire period.  If you just want to strip all NAs, then just use the first filter statement and you are done.  You obviously don't need to use POSIXct if you've already got your dates encoded correctly another way.

EDIT: w/ function wrapper so you can use lapply:

```
library(dplyr)

# Get some example data
df <- read.csv ("L112FN0M.262.csv")
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
dfnull <- df
dfnull$precip <- NA

# list of 3 input data frames to test, 2nd one has precip all NA
df.list <- list(df, dfnull, df)  

# Function to do the filtering; returns list of data frames to keep or null
filterprecip <- function(d) {
    if (nrow(filter(d, !is.na(precip), datetime >= as.POSIXct("2015-04-01"), datetime < as.POSIXct("2015-12-01"))) > 
        0) {
        return(filter(d, datetime >= as.POSIXct("2015-04-01"), datetime < as.POSIXct("2015-12-01")))
    }
}

# Function to remove NULLS in returned list
# (Credit to Hadley Wickham: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e8/help/09/12/8102.html)
compact <- function(x) Filter(Negate(is.null), x) 

# Filter the list
results <- compact(lapply(df.list, filterprecip))

# Check that you got a list of 2 data frames in the right date range
str(results)
```

Comment: Yes! I want to retain NAs in the data frame if there are also valid precip values and only want to discard a dataframe from `lst2` if there are NAs for the entire period `2015-04-01 to 2015-11-30`. Your code removes rows with `NAs` during this date range instead of retaining them? Only subset data for this date range if precip has both NAs and values (and/or values only) but discard that dataframe if precip is all NAs.

Comment: The code uses `df.sub` to determine if the data frame should be kept: it removes all NAs in the date range and stores that result in `df.sub`.  Then the second chunk decides whether to keep the df: if `df.sub` is empty, there were only NAs, so don't add it to your output list.  If `df.sub` has some content, then grab the entire target date range from `df` as `df.result` and add it to your output list.

Comment: thanks. Can you please apply it on a list object to make it complete? Many thanks.

Comment: See my edit above with the code in a function and an example.  Probably an R guru on here could make it more efficient, but I think this does what you want.

Comment: great function. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the code on my large files, it did most of the job except this part which I indicated in the question "All dataframes in `lst3` should have equal length with days and hours without `precip` denoted as `NA`". Here I want to get all dfs with precip value, generate a datetime as above for all dfs with precip. So each `df` will have `datetime` from `2015-04-01 to 2015-11-30`. Hours with no precip value should have `NA`. Therefore all dfs in `lst3` will have equal rows. Please help edit your code to include this part.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've written, is sounds like you're just interested in subsetting your list of files if data exists in the *precip* column **for this specific date range**.

```
> valuesExist <- function(df,start="2015-04-01 0:00:00",end="2015-11-30 23:59:59"){
+ sub.df <- df[df$datetime>=start & df$datetime>=end,]
+ if(sum(is.na(sub.df$precip)==nrow(df)){return(FALSE)}else{return(TRUE)}
+ }
> lst2.bool <- lapply(lst2, valuesExist)
> lst2 <- lst2[lst2.bool]
> lst3 <- lapply(lst2, function(x) {x[x$datetime>="2015-04-01 0:00:00" & x$datetime>="2015-11-30 23:59:59",]}
> sapply(names(lst2), function (x)  write.csv(lst3[[x]],file = paste0(names(lst2[x]), ".csv"),row.names = FALSE))
```

**If you want to have a dynamic start and end time**, toss a variable with these values into the valueExist function and replace the string timestamp in the lst3 assignment with that same variable.

If you wanted to combine the two lapply loops into one, be my guest, but I prefer having a boolean variable when I'm subsetting.

Comment: shouldn't this be `sub.df <- df[df$datetime>=start & df$datetime<=end,]` with a `<=end`? I am trying to apply the function to my `lst2`. USing @Nat's description above, retain NAs in the data frame if there are also valid precip values and discard if there are NAs for the entire period date range. I get an error here: `lst2 <- lst2[lst2.bool]` `Error in lst2[lst2.bool] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Comment: Haha, yeah it should be <=end. That's what I get for typing things manually instead of just copy-pasting.